# Jquery DataTable Horizontol Scroll

Tags: jquery, datatable

Am using Jquery DataTable(http://datatables.net). Am trying with some demo for Horizontol Scroll bar

When i set the "sScrollX" property. My DataTable DOM is like below one

```
<div class="dataTables_scroll">
<div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px none; width: 100%;">
<div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
<table id="resultsDatatable" class="dataTable" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 110%;" aria-describedby="resultsDatatable_info">
<thead>
<tbody>
```

Where am getting Multiple Thead and my UI is messy. If i remove everything is fine but i wont get Horizontol scroll

What am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) of the problem?

Comment: how do i add the how do i add the Datatable plugin to Fiddle ? can you share the link for external resources for DataTableDatatable plugin to Fiddle ?

Comment: Add `http://datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.js` to external resources. Also here is a list of other [datatable scripts](http://datatables.net/download/).

Comment: Thanks DOM. Am not able to replicate that scenario in Fiddle. itz working fine there

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong - DataTables has to split the table into two when scrolling is enabled (only way of doing it across all browsers), and to keep the column widths matched, the thead element is duplicated. Visually you should not see that at all. Can you link to a demo page showing the problem?