# Jquery DataTable UI Issue -- when to call fnAdjustColumnSizing

Tags: jquery, datatables

Currently working on Jquery DataTable

similar to this issue [Jquery DataTable Horizontol Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084697/jquery-datatable-horizontol-scroll?noredirect=1#comment23075633_16084697)

Some how i managed to come closer to the solution using fnAdjustColumnSizing()

My UI is messed up as am hiding the DataTable at page load.

Then i found that you need to call `fnAdjustColumnSizing` on resize in Datatable.net links

```
 $(window).on('resize', function () {
        oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    });
```

But now my problem is UI is fixed only if i resize my window not on page load or after the DataTable is loaded

Whatz the alternative to fix Column sizing or to call resize ?

Thanks