# Where to call fnAdjustColumnSizing in Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Am working on the UI issue i got in Datatables.net when scrollx is applied to the table.

Thanks to this [Jquery DataTable UI Issue -- when to call fnAdjustColumnSizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162782/jquery-datatable-ui-issue-when-to-call-fnadjustcolumnsizing) but waiting for answer

Am trying to apply resize

```
 $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    });
```

But this fix my issue only if i resize my browser. else my UI look messy.

Also i tried applying in InitComplete

```
"fnInitComplete": function () {
                console.log("Compelete");
                this.fnAdjustColumnSizing(true);
            },
```

But still itz not fixed until i resize.

Where do i need to call fnAdjustColumnSizing so that it fixes the UI on load complete ?

Comment: i m facing the same problem have u find any solution ??

Comment: @Youddh try calling the line and see if it works.Answer below

Answer (score 0):

Itz bit late but this worked for me.

After completeing your DataTable code

```
 if (oTable != "") {
        oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing(); //oTable is the variable which holds DataTable

    }
```

and also add inside your resize as well.

Thanks